# Python Dataframe strange behavior

Tags: python, dataframe

This is quite strange. I have no idea what is happening.
I have this dataframe:

```
df
Out[52]: 
      userID itemID  rating
0        196    242     3.0
1        186    302     3.0
2         22    377     1.0
3        244     51     2.0
4        166    346     1.0
     ...    ...     ...
99995    880    476     3.0
99996    716    204     5.0
99997    276   1090     1.0
99998     13    225     2.0
99999     12    203     3.0


type(df)
Out[55]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

df.columns
Out[56]: Index(['userID', 'itemID', 'rating'], dtype='object')
```

However, when I ask

```
df[df['userID']==196 ]
Out[53]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [userID, itemID, rating]
Index: []
```

Or

```
df.loc[df['userID']==196 ]
Out[54]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [userID, itemID, rating]
Index: []
```

Note that there is the 'userID'==196 from the extract above.

To be precise, this dataframe comes from the library Surprise:

```
from surprise import Dataset
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')
df = pd.DataFrame(data.__dict__['raw_ratings'], columns=['user_id','item_id','rating','timestamp'])
df.drop(columns=['timestamp'],inplace=True)
df.rename({'user_id':'userID','item_id':'itemID'},axis=1,inplace=True)
```

What is happening here?

Comment: What is the type of userID column ?

Comment: Yes, you have found the answer. It strangely is a string.

Comment: df['userID'].iloc[0]
Out[59]: '196'